# Map doesn't update location

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location, android-alertdialog

I wanted to make the google map in this activity updated once I press the alertdialog choices(emails). The location has been set manually but it doesn't update. It just stays in the alertdialog and the google map just refreshes but not going to the location coordinate and it return as 0,0.

```
    public class MapsTrack extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
            GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
            GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
            LocationListener,
            View.OnClickListener {

        //Our Map
        private GoogleMap mMap;


        //To store longitude and latitude from map
        private double longitude;
        private double latitude;

        //Buttons
        private ImageButton buttonSearch;
        private ImageButton buttonCurrent;

        private static final int MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

        //Google ApiClient
        private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
        Location location;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_track);
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            //Initializing googleapi client
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();

            //Initializing views and adding onclick listeners
            buttonSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
            buttonCurrent = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonCurrent);
            buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
            buttonCurrent.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            googleApiClient.connect();
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
            super.onStop();
        }

        //Getting current location
        private void getCurrentLocation() {
            //Creating a location object
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            if (location != null) {
                //Getting longitude and latitude
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();

                //moving the map to location
                moveMap();
            }
        }

        //Function to move the map
        private void moveMap() {
            //String to display current latitude and longitude
            String msg = latitude + ", " + longitude;

            //Creating a LatLng Object to store Coordinates
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            //Adding marker to map
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng) //setting position
                    .draggable(true) //Making the marker draggable
                    .title("Current Location")); //Adding a title


            //Moving the camera
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            //Animating the camera
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

            //Displaying current coordinates in toast
            Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
            mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
        }


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
            //Clearing all the markers
            mMap.clear();

            //Adding a new marker to the current pressed position
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .draggable(true));
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
            //Getting the coordinates
            latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
            longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

            //Moving the map
            moveMap();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == buttonCurrent) {
                getCurrentLocation();
                moveMap();
            } else if (v == buttonSearch) {

                final String[] names = new String[]{"ijad_wiz@gmail.com", "nadiaf33@yahoo.com"};
                final String name = names[1];
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsTrack.this);
AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_inflate, null);
                alertDialog.setView(convertView);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Track!");
                ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                alertDialog.show();

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        switch (name) {
                            case "email1@gmail.com":
                            latitude = 3.22094;
                            longitude = 101.724866;
                                LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(3.1466,101.6958);
                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng1));
                                moveMap();
                                break;
                            case "email2@yahoo.com":
                            latitude = 48.8584;
                            longitude = 2.2945;
                                LatLng latLng2 = new LatLng(48.8584, 2.2945);
                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng2));
                                moveMap();
                                break;
                    }
                }

            });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
            if (requestCode == MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (permissions.length == 1 &&
                        permissions[0] == android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION &&
                        grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    // Permission was denied. Display an error message.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the code to get the `AlertDialog` (instead of the `AlertDialog Builder`):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

// Then you can call on your 
// lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
alert.cancel();
// }
```

Also, you are not setting your latitude and longitude variables in this block:

```
LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(3.1466,101.6958);
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng1));
moveMap();
```

so it probably moves the camera and the moves back to a previous position.

Comment: Okay, added the alertdialog now, but the map still doesn't move to the specified location. how do you mean by not setting latitude and longitude variables?

Comment: Your `moveMap` function uses the `latitude` and `longitude` variables to move the camera (again), however before calling it, you don't set the values for these variables on your switch statement.

Comment: Thanks! It works now but when I press the first email, it goes to the second email's coordinate.

Comment: The error is that when you do `switch (name)` you are always comparing with the second email, because of this line `final String name = names[1];`. You should use `switch (names[position])`.

Comment: changed to (names[position]) but error "Array type expected"

Comment: yep, is there anything that I forgot to add?

Comment: Try changing to `switch (names.get(position))`

Comment: cannot resolve method get(int). the get is red. maybe the problem is the position?

Comment: Did you change anything else on your code? It doesn't make sense. If names has been declared like this `final String[] names = new String[]{"ijad_wiz@gmail.com", "nadiaf33@yahoo.com"};`, you should be able to reference using `names[position]`, considering that position is an integer pointing to the index of the item clicked. Can you place a breakpoint near the `switch` and inspect the values of names and position variables?

Comment: I removed String name = names[1]; and renamed the switch line as switch(names[position]), now everything runs perfectly. Thank you sir for your time! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Great to know. :)